# How to define MyApp in Redux-thunk and Polymer 2.x

Tags: redux, polymer, redux-thunk, polymer-2.x

[On this blog page](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/19/project-structure-for-using-redux-with-polymer-20), Captain Codeman describes how to implement Redux with Polymer 2.x. However, when I use it, I get the following error complaining about the variable `MyApp` being undefined. Where and how should I define the the `MyApp` variable?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined
>       at my-redux-store.html:23
>       at my-redux-store.html:42
>   (anonymous) @ my-redux-store.html:23
>   (anonymous) @ my-redux-store.html:42
>   user-setter-behavior.html:114 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReduxBehavior is not defined
>       at user-setter-behavior.html:114
>   (anonymous) @ user-setter-behavior.html:114

my-redux-store.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer-redux/polymer-redux.html">

<link rel="import" href="my-redux-actions.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-redux-middleware.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-redux-reducers.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-redux-selectors.html">

<script>
(function() {

  const composeEnhancers = typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({})
    : Redux.compose;

  const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
    Redux.applyMiddleware(...MyApp.middleware),
  );

  const store = Redux.createStore(MyApp.rootReducer, enhancer);

  const reduxMixin = PolymerRedux(store);

  /* @mixinFunction */
  const actionsMixin = (superClass) => {
    return class extends reduxMixin(superClass) {
      static get actions() {
        return MyApp.actions
      }
    }
  }

  /* @mixinFunction */
  MyApp.ReduxMixin = Polymer.dedupingMixin(actionsMixin);

}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyApp` is just a global namespace, just like the `Polymer` object. It's explained in the previous article that it starts by referencing.

```
MyApp = {}
```

or, if you are using strict mode, maybe:

```
window.MyApp = {}
```

You can also create it if it isn't defined using something like:

```
MyApp = MyApp || {}
```